# How to extract and replace integer and float values from an object column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a column of strings and numbers. Hence the data type is object. I would like to extract all the integers/floats. I want to categorize a range of integers to some particular class. Hence I want to replace the number with its class name.
I tried the following:

```
diabetes_data[diabetes_data['diag_1'].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]['diag_1']).replace(['[1-100)'],'Circulatory', inplace = True)
```

I'm trying to replace numbers in range 1-100 with class name circulatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1** which is nice and short, checks with [.mask()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) if the value is in `range(1, 100)` and if so replaces it:

```
diabetes_data = pd.DataFrame(data={'diag_1': ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 101]})

diabetes_data['diag_1'] = diabetes_data['diag_1'].mask(
    diabetes_data['diag_1'].isin(range(1, 100)), 
    'Circulatory',
)
```

**Solution 2:** You can also use [.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with some regex to solve this:

```
diabetes_data['diag_1'] = (diabetes_data['diag_1']
    .astype(str)
    .str.replace('^[1-9]{1,2}$|^100$', 'Circulatory'))
```

**Solution 3:** Use [np.isreal()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) to figure out which rows are a number and then change those rows using [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = diabetes_data['diag_1'].map(np.isreal)

diabetes_data['diag_1'].loc[mask] = np.where(
    (diabetes_data['diag_1'].loc[mask] >= 1) 
    & (diabetes_data['diag_1'].loc[mask] <= 100), 
    'Circulatory', 
    diabetes_data['diag_1'].loc[mask]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a function:

```
def change_values(x):
    if str(x).isdigit() and x>0 and x<=100:
        return 'category'
    else:
        return x

diabetes_data['diag_1'] = diabetes_data['diag_1'].apply(lambda x: change_values(x))
```

or just written out in the apply()

```
diabetes_data['diag_1'] = diabetes_data['diag_1'].apply(lambda x: 'category' if str(x).isdigit() and x>0 and x<=100 else x)
```

Depending on the size of the dataframe, there may be a faster way using .loc rather than iterating using lambda.